# Problem with TP-Link Wireless TL-WN851ND PCI Adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless, pci

I've installed a new Wireless PCI Adapter, called TL-WN851ND on my PC.

My operative system identifies it and I can connect to my lan.

When I try to use the browser for surfing the net, I lose connection and the wireless adapter stops to work correctly.

Can anyone give me an idea to solve this?
I need a solution because I don't want to install Windows.

I post the output of some commands:

Thanks.

**lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2**

```
04:05.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:002d] (rev 01)
   Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0300]
   Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

**rfkill list all**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: VT6102/VT6103 [Rhine-II]
       vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
       physical id: 12
       bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
       logical name: enp0s18
       version: 7c
       serial: 00:1d:60:22:df:27
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=via-rhine driverversion=1.5.1 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.107 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=8 mingnt=3 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:23 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:fbcff800-fbcff8ff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:04:05.0
       logical name: wlp4s5
       version: 01
       serial: 98:de:d0:8c:07:54
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-57-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.108 latency=168 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:19 memory:fbef0000-fbefffff
```

**iwconfig**

```
wlp4s5    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Rete_2.4GHz"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: 60:E3:27:9A:84:94   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:101   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s18   no wireless extensions.
```

**route -n**

```
Tabella di routing IP del kernel
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s5
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s5
```

**cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**ping -c 3 8.8.4.4**

```
PING 8.8.4.4 (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=62.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=61.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=61.5 ms

--- 8.8.4.4 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 61.546/61.837/62.218/0.347 ms
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please help us help you. Please edit your question to include the output of these two terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`
 and `rfkill list all`

Comment: @AndroidDev Thank for you advice. I've included the output of the commands.

Comment: Before further troubleshooting make sure you have the recommended wireless encryption settings, *at the router*: Always WPA2-AES, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode (typical default settings for many ISP provided routers) and certainly not TKIP (idem).

Comment: Also please post code as text, within code tags, not as screenshots.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I've post all the code as text. My wifi uses WPA2-AES.

Comment: Had very similar problems with the same wifi card (but apparently a different chipset?) https://askubuntu.com/questions/987845/wifi-slow-and-disconnects-tp-link-tl-wn851nd-realtek-rtl8192ee/987846#987846